# how to consume wcf service with ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wcf

i have a rails app must consume wcf services provided by asp.net, are there any ruby clients for wcf?

Answer (score 12):

Are you in control of the web service? Can you change the web.config a bit? (You indicate Asp.Net so I guess that means the WCF Service is hosted in IIS.)

A WCF service can be [exposed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733051.aspx) as a regular old web-service. It's one of the promises of WCF: the same service can be exposed via many bindings with nothing but a configuration change.

```
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IServiceContract">
```

Then you can call it from Ruby like so:

```
require 'soap/wsdlDriver'   
soap = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new("http://host/SomeService.svc?wsdl").create_rpc_driver
soap.ServiceMethod(:param1=> Value, :param2 => AnotherValue)
```

Comment: thanks brendanjerwin. but i cannot control the wfc services :(

Comment: Well, then it should work. I don't think there is any WCF-ness to be dealt with... Try my ruby sample. If you are still having problems then it's probably just an issue with the way you are calling the method.